# jquery turn of function and variable setInterval loop?

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I have code (it's work) but I need:
    1. after clicking (".my div") function should stoped
    2. After that function should started after variable time period (may be 10 second, 15, 5, 30).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
if (document.getElementById("monitor") !== null){
   var counter = 200;
   var myFunction = function(){
      clearInterval(interval);
      counter *= 10;
      interval = setInterval(myFunction, counter);
   };
   var interval = setInterval(myFunction, counter);
   setInterval(function() { Piano.anim(); }, interval);
}
    Piano.anim = function(){...},1000);
};;
```

Code worked always, and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Sounds a bit vague, you want it to stop but yet it needs to be repeated?

Comment: After pushing div, my function should stoped, and started after variable time period (may be 10 second, 15, 5, 30).

Comment: i have hard time to understand logic behind your code especially the use of `interval` variable

Comment: I'm a bit lost here. So you are creating an interval which calls `myFunction` with time `counter`. Then you start another interval calling `anim()` which uses the interval ID of the first one as the time? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but you could try this logic:

```
var interval = null;

// the function to be called each second
function x(){
    console.log('running');
}

//start interval
function startInterval(){
    interval = setInterval(x, 1000);
}

// called at (".my div") click
// stop the interval, then restart it after 10 seconds
// save the timeout so it's not called more than once
var restartTimeout = null;
function interruptInterval(){
    if(interval && !restartTimeout){
        clearInterval(interval);
        restartTimeout = setTimeout(startInterval, 10000);
    }
}

$(".my div").click(interruptInterval);

startInterval();
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't add rank (I'm new here and haven't enought rank for voting)! Thanl you so much again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [clearInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) and then create a new interval for repeating it after some time with [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
var interval = setInterval(myFunction, counter);
//after clicking the .my div
clearInterval(interval);
var second_interval = setInterval(myFunction, counter);//Maybe an other function than myFunction?
```

Comment: don't understand how to use several intervals. May be example?